# Who names Seth?

Tags: genesis, adam

In Genesis 4:25 it states

> וַיֵּ֨דַע אָדָ֥ם עוֹד֙ אֶת־אִשְׁתּ֔וֹ וַתֵּ֣לֶד בֵּ֔ן וַתִּקְרָ֥א אֶת־שְׁמ֖וֹ שֵׁ֑ת כִּ֣י שָֽׁת־לִ֤י אֱלֹהִים֙ זֶ֣רַע אַחֵ֔ר תַּ֣חַת הֶ֔בֶל כִּ֥י הֲרָג֖וֹ קָֽיִן׃

I would like to know whom is speaking, is it Adam or his wife (Hava)?

Answer (score 4):

וַתִּקְרָ֥א אֶת־שְׁמ֖וֹ שֵׁ֑ת means "And she called his name 'Seth'".

Hava is speaking in the portion of the verse in question. וַתִּקְרָ֥א is the [qal](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/43._Its_Form_and_Meaning) [imperfect](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/47._The_Imperfect_and_its_Inflexion) 3fs of *qara'* (he called). 3fs stands for third feminine singular meaning one woman is the subject. The subject simply being a pronoun in this case. Hebrew verbs change form depending on the subject. A prefix and suffix combination determines if the subject of the verb is first, second, or third person; masculine, feminine, or common (for example, first person verbs make no distinction in form between masculine speakers and feminine speakers so the form is considered "common"); and singular or plural. If the speaker wants to simply use the pronoun as subject, they don't even have to add a stand-alone pronoun, though Hebrew allows them to if so desired. A separated subject (a proper name or a noun like "the king") usually comes after the verb in the Hebrew text.

The feminine pronoun in this translation refers back to Adam's wife whom he had marital relations with and then bore a son.